# How to overcome SONAR issue :: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2259

Tags: java, sql, sonarqube

My piece of code looks like below:

```
public static File intoCSV(String fileName){
    File csvFile = new File(FilenameUtils.getName(fileName));
    Connection connection = ConnectionUtility.getConnection();
    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(SELECT)) {
        //code to write to CSV file
    } catch() {
    }
    return csvFile
}
```

Where i have declared a SELECT as constant with select query string.

Any suggestion to make change or can be avoided getting SONAR issue at line "ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(SELECT))". I'm getting Nullcheck of statement at line xx of value previously dereferenced in intoCSV(string)

Comment: Are you sure that `statement` is not `null`?

Comment: If and only connection fails..

Comment: What about checking for this and making sure that code isn't executed if the connection fails?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete (and not even syntactically valid) so it is impossible to say what the cause of the SONAR rule failure is.  However, we can make an educated guess.

You say that:

```
  ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(SELECT)
```

is flagged for dereferencing a `null`.  Therefore, SONAR thinks that either `statement` or `SELECT` could be `null`.   Assuming that `Connection` is actually a `java.sql.Connection` instance, the preceding line

```
  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
```

cannot assign null to `statement`.  (That would violate the JDBC spec.)

So that means that `SELECT` is what SONAR is concerned about.

---

Of course ... this could be wrong.  But we need a **REAL** [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get any further with this.

It is also possible that SONAR is wrong.  (Bug checker rules can have bugs in the ...)